# Why all these `HADOOP_HOME` and Winutils errors with Spark on Windows if Hadoop not used?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm running Spark 3.3.0 on Windows 10 using Java 11. I'm not using Hadoop. Every time I run something, it gives errors like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:978)
```

First of all, even the link https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems in the error message is broken. The update link is apparently https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/WindowsProblems, which basically says that Hadoop needs Winutils. But I'm not using Hadoop. I'm just using Spark to process some CSV files locally.

Secondly, I want my project to build with Maven and run with pure Java, without requiring the user to install some third-party software. If this Winutil stuff needs to be installed, it should be included in some Maven dependency.

Why is all this Hadoop/Winutils stuff needed if I'm not using Hadoop, and how do I get around it so that my project will build in Maven and run with pure Java like a Java project should?

Comment: One solution is to run Spark in Linux/WSL2 instead of Windows CMD. The whole reason Winutils is needed, only on windows, is because Spark depends on Unix permission sets

Comment: "The whole reason Winutils is needed, only on windows, is because Spark depends on Unix permission sets". Java handles Unix permission sets just fine since like Java 7. If you dig in the code, you'll find the real problem is that `RawLocalFileSystem` _assumes_ that the only way to get to them is shelling out to some OS command. So why not improve `RawLocalFileSystem` to use Java on Windows? Or is there a way to tell Spark to use a different Hadoop `FileSystem` implementation that uses pure Java? Creativity, people!

Comment: "It's an open source project. Make a pull request or open a JIRA instead of complain". Sure, I'll be glad to. But I'm asking here first how it works and what the options are. And the only compliant is toward any attitudes of "that's just the way it is; don't try to investigate solutions", which is the attitude that originally closed this question before it was reopened.

Comment: It's a pain and if someone wants to add the ability to downgrade hadoop`s file:// filesystem to not need the libs, i will help review the hadoop PRs. meanwhile, grab a build of winutils.exe for your hadoop binaries  https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils

Comment: I'm still astounded at the initial response to my question. This was a completely legitimate question, with an understandable explanation and a feasible workaround possible. Yet someone immediately closed the question, and then I got all sorts of push-back on the question itself, as if I were asking the gods for something sinful. I'm guessing part of came from newbie developers who had no clue how things worked and didn't even understand the question. Disappointingly even some experienced Hadoop developers seemed hostile to questioning the status quo. But I do appreciate stevel's assistance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### TL;DR

I have created a local implementation of Hadoop `FileSystem` that bypasses Winutils on Windows (and indeed should work on any Java platform). The [GlobalMentor Hadoop Bare Naked Local FileSystem](https://github.com/globalmentor/hadoop-bare-naked-local-fs) source code is available on GitHub and can be specified as a dependency from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.globalmentor/hadoop-bare-naked-local-fs).

1. If you have an application that needs Hadoop local `FileSystem` support without relying on Winutils, import the latest [`com.globalmentor:hadoop-bare-naked-local-fs`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.globalmentor/hadoop-bare-naked-local-fs) library into your project, e.g. in Maven for v0.1.0:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.globalmentor</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-bare-naked-local-fs</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Then specify that you want to use the Bare Local File System implementation `com.globalmentor.apache.hadoop.fs.BareLocalFileSystem` for the `file` scheme. (`BareLocalFileSystem` internally uses `NakedLocalFileSystem`.)  The following example does this for Spark in Java:

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Foo Bar").master("local").getOrCreate();
spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().setClass("fs.file.impl", BareLocalFileSystem.class, FileSystem.class);
```

*Note that you may still get warnings that "HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset" and "Did not find winutils.exe". This is because the Winutils kludge permeates the Hadoop code and is hard-coded at a low-level, executed statically upon class loading, even for code completely unrelated to file access. More explanation can be found on the [project page on GitHub](https://github.com/globalmentor/hadoop-bare-naked-local-fs). See also [HADOOP-13223: winutils.exe is a bug nexus and should be killed with an axe.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13223))*

#### How Spark uses Hadoop `FileSystem`

Spark uses the Hadoop `FileSystem` API as a means for writing output to disk, e.g. for local CSV or JSON output. It pulls in the entire Hadoop client libraries (currently `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client-api:3.3.2`), containing various `FileSystem` implementations. These implementations use the Java [service loader framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to automatically register several implementations for several schemes, including among others:

- `org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem`
- `org.apache.hadoop.fs.viewfs.ViewFileSystem`
- `org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpFileSystem`
- `org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpsFileSystem`
- `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem`
- …

Each of these file systems indicates which scheme it supports. In particular `org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem` indicates it supports the `file` scheme, and it is used by default to access the local file system. It in turn uses the `org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem` internally, which is the `FileSystem` implementation ultimately responsible for requiring Winutils.

But it is possible to override the Hadoop configuration and specify another `FileSystem` implementation. Spark creates a special `Configuration` for Hadoop in `org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.newHadoopConf(…)` ultimately combining all the sources `core-default.xml`, `core-site.xml`, `mapred-default.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, `yarn-default.xml`, `yarn-site.xml`, and `__spark_hadoop_conf__.xml`, if any are present. Then Hadoop's `FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(String scheme, Configuration conf)` looks for the `FileSystem` implementation to use by looking up a configuration for the scheme (in this case `file`) in the form `fs.${scheme}.impl` (i.e. `fs.file.impl` in this case).

Thus if you want to specify another  local file system implementation to use, you'll need to somehow get `fs.file.impl` into the configuration. Rather than creating a local configuration file if you are accessing Spark programmatically, you can set it via the Spark session, as explained in the introduction.

#### Why Winutils

The Hadoop `FileSystem` API in large part assumes a *nix file system. The current Hadoop local `FileSystem` implementation uses native *nix libraries or opens shell processes and directly runs *nix commands. The current local `FileSystem` implementation for Windows limps along with a huge kludge: a set of binary artifacts called [Winutils](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils) that a Hadoop contributor created, providing a special back-door subsystem on Windows that Hadoop can access instead of *nix libraries and shell commands. (See [HADOOP-13223: winutils.exe is a bug nexus and should be killed with an axe.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13223))

However detection and required support of Winutils is actually hard-coded in the Hadoop at a low-level—even in code that has nothing to do with the file system! For example when Spark starts up, even a simple `Configuration` initialization in the Hadoop code invokes `StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("true", valueString)`, and the `StringUtils` class has a static reference to `Shell`, which has a static initialization block that looks for Winutils and produces a warning if not found. ‍♂️ (In fact this is the source of the warnings that were the motivation for this Stack Overflow question in the first place.)

#### Workaround to use `FileSystem` without Winutils

Irrespective of the warnings, the larger issue is getting `FileSystem` to work without needing Winutils. This is paradoxically both a simpler and also a much more complex project than it would first appear. One one hand it is not too difficult to use updated Java API calls instead of Winutils to access the local file system; I have done that already in the [GlobalMentor Hadoop Bare Naked Local FileSystem](https://github.com/globalmentor/hadoop-bare-naked-local-fs). But weeding out Winutils completely is much more complex and difficult. The current `LocalFileSystem` and `RawLocalFileSystem` implementations have evolved haphazardly, with halway-implemented features scattered about, special-case code for ill-documented corner cases, and implementation-specific assumptions permeating the design itself.

The example was already given above of `Configuration` accessing `Shell` and trying to pull in Winutils just upon classloading during startup. At the `FileSystem` level Winutils-related logic isn't contained to `RawLocalFileSystem`, which would have allowed it to easily be overridden, but instead relies on the static [`FileUtil`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.java) class which is like a separate file system implementation that relies on Winutils and can't be modified. For example here is `FileUtil` code that would need to be updated, unfortunately independently of the `FileSystem` implementation:

```java
  public static String readLink(File f) {
    /* NB: Use readSymbolicLink in java.nio.file.Path once available. Could
     * use getCanonicalPath in File to get the target of the symlink but that
     * does not indicate if the given path refers to a symlink.
     */
    …
    try {
      return Shell.execCommand(
          Shell.getReadlinkCommand(f.toString())).trim();
    } catch (IOException x) {
      return "";
    }
```

Apparently there is a "new [`Stat`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Stat.java) based implementation" of many methods, but `RawLocalFileSystem` instead uses a deprecated implementations such as `DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus`, which is full of workarounds and special-cases, is package-private so it can't be accessed by subclasses, yet can't be removed because of [HADOOP-9652](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9652). The `useDeprecatedFileStatus` switch is hard-coded so that it can't be modified by a subclass, forcing a re-implementation of everything it touches. In other words, even the new, less-kludgey approach is switched off in the code, has been for years, and no one seems to be paying it any mind.

### Summary

In summary, Winutils is hard-coded at a low-level throughout the code, even in logic unrelated to file access, and the current implementation is a hodge-podge of deprecated and undeprecated code switched on or off by hard-coded flags that were put in place when errors appeared with new changes. It's a mess, and it's been that way for years. No one really cares, and instead keeps building on unstable sand (`ViewFs` anyone?) rather than going back and fixing the foundation. If Hadoop can't even fix large swathes of deprecated file access code consolidated in one place, do you think they are going to fix the Winutils kludge that permeates multiple classes at a low level?

I'm not holding my breath. Instead I'll be content with the workaround I've written which writes to the file system via the Java API, bypassing Winutils for the most common use case (writing to the local file system without using symlinks and without the need for the sticky bit permission), which is sufficient to get Spark accessing the local file system on Windows.

Comment: nice work. regarding the deprecation, a big issue there is so much code uses nominally internal methods that things break, especially in the fs apis. getting rid of winutils is easier than some of this other stuff. A fundamental issue is that the work focuses on hdfs/ozone/cloud stores and as the developers tend to use mac/linux, we don't get irritated by the winutils stuff ourselves. It does have to die with an axe, but we have so many other things which are critical it just gets neglected

Comment: Thanks for this library and for the detailed write up. You made my life simpler today.

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback, Johan. This initial version version uses minimal overrides to get basic functionality working. I didn't have time to rewrite everything from scratch, so I depended on the existing "raw" implementation in many places. If you run into something that doesn't work right, please file a ticket on the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/globalmentor/hadoop-bare-naked-local-fs) so I can continue improving it.

Comment: Thanks for this job (Hadoop Bare Naked Local FileSystem), it seems we can get rid of winutils and hadoop.dll completely. Made my day!

Answer (score 2):

There is a longstanding JIRA for this...for anyone running spark standalone on laptop there's no needed to provide those posix permissions. is there

[LocalFS to support ability to disable permission get/set; remove need for winutils](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17839)

This is related to [HADOOP-13223
winutils.exe is a bug nexus and should be killed with an axe](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13223).
It is *only* people running spark on windows who hit this problem, and nobody is putting in the work to fix it. If someone was, I will help review/nurture in.

Comment: Thanks for these references, Steve. In a few days I'll try to dig into this and respond further on the tickets themselves regarding actual implementation.

Comment: easiest to grab a built of the exe; its just hard enough to build it's not done with an ASF release. and to be ruthless, linux arm64 binaries has more priority because that does get used in production, reducing costs at scale.

Comment: "easiest to grab a built of the exe". But why should the latest technology force me to use a kludge that lowers the security of my project and moreover breaks my "just use `mvn install` build"? Why can't we do things right? I like your idea about working on the tickets better, and I already intend to look into them and see if I can contribute. Let's not further these kludges.

Comment: in order to implement the security needed for YARN to security download and then run artifacts it needs posix permissions; winutlls delivers that and has since before java native added the APIs. nobody deploys yarn clusters on hadoop right now, but an MSFT engineer has taken that up again. For using file:// URLs through spark, the feature isn't needed and it should be optional, IMO.

Comment: "… since before java native added the APIs …" But Java has added the APIs now. Besides, the whole point of this ticket is not Hadoop, but Spark. You might say "Spark uses Hadoop's `FileSystem` API." But it doesn't have to. And if it does, it doesn't have to use this particular `FileSystem` implementation, or in this way.

Comment: @GarretWilson i agree. someone needs to do that patch though

Comment: I will look at it as soon as possible. First I'm wasting a day or two creating a SLF4J 2.x workaround because Spark decided to directly access `StaticLoggerBinder`. See [SPARK-40489](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-40489). That's almost done, thankfully.

Comment: stevel thank you for your reply and encouragement. Please see my answer, and my published workaround `FileSystem` implementation. And your offer that "[i]f someone [were to put in the work to fix it], I will help review/nurture in" is tempting; I would love to do the work. I am probably as qualified as anyone to work in this area, and it's something I would enjoy doing. But your comment that this would be a simple "patch" is naive, though; this permeates even unrelated code at a low level. It would take significant effort, and in the end I doubt Apache has the will to make significant fixes.

Comment: Nevertheless stevel if you are serious about wanting this fixed, let me know how we can discuss this further. I don't intend to waste six months (and oodles of dollars of my time) rewriting `FileSystem` only to find out that Apache won't accept the changes. If Apache or some company actually cares enough to see this fixed, probably the most feasible and pragmatic way forward would be for them to hire me and reserve a certain percentage of my time for working on the Hadoop file system code. But it's a larger discussion not appropriate for Stack Overflow Q/A comments. Let me know the best forum.

Comment: This is a really really good piece of work. Linked to it off my winutils readme. Sparkk-on-laptop is a legit use and people shouldn't have to suffer. Get on the hadoop common-dev list and discuss what can be done there. At the very least we need to try and isolate things -though we have to worry so much about breaking external code that a cleanup is hard.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is a replacement *execution framework* for mapreduce, not a "Hadoop replacement".

Spark uses Hadoop libraries for Filesystem access, including local filesystem. As shown in your error `org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem`

It also uses winutils as a sort of shim to implement Unix (POSIX?) chown/chmod commands to determine  file permissions on top of Windows directories.

> tell Spark to use a different file system implementation than RawLocalFileSystem?

Yes, use a different URI than default `file://`

E.g. `spark.csv("nfs://path/file.csv")`

Or s3a or install HDFS, or GlusterFS, etc. for a distributed filesystem. After all Spark is meant to be distributed processing engine; if you're only handling small local files, it's not the best tool.

Comment: "Spark uses Hadoop libraries for Filesystem access, including local filesystem." So is there some minimal Hadoop dependency I can add, via some Maven coordinates, just to access the file system without the need to install Winutils?

Comment: No. Winutils is a C library, I think. Spark pulls all the Java dependencies it needs

Comment: More specifically, as mentioned in the winutils readme, it's not distributed with Spark (or Hadoop) because it can have its own vulnerabilities and many Apache projects simply don't have Windows build systems/tests.

Comment: "Yes, use a different URI than default `file://`" Ah, now we're getting somewhere. So what Hadoop `FileSystem` implementation is `nfs:` mapped to? And where are the mappings, so that I could change them if I wanted to via Spark? "…  if you're only handling small local files, it's not the best tool." Well maybe I want to write a prototype of the large-scale version on my laptop before deploying it in the cloud.

Comment: I'm not sure about NFS in particular, but I know http/s and s/ftp are in the Hadoop source repo https://github.com/apache/hadoop/search?q=%22extends+FileSystem%22&type=

Comment: Thanks, I'll look. And if you find out where the mapping is set up so that I could map `file://` to my own file system implementation (yes and contribute it back), that would be helpful too.

Comment: In the conf folder of Spark, there may be a `core-site.xml` file. In there, there's a setting `fs.defaultFS`, that'll set the default URI, for example an S3 bucket or HDFS namenode. There's another setting called `fs.{name}.impl` that should any JVM class that extends the Hadoop Filesystem interface

Comment: I'm guessing there may not be a `core-site.xml`, as I'm simply including Spark via Maven dependencies. That's the whole point of the question—I don't want to deploy other standalone applications for my application. I want it all to build cross-platform from a Maven project. But you've given me some good pointers, thanks. I'll do more research.

Comment: Spark looks for those xml files by default in `SPARK_HOME/conf` of `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` env vars. You can also put them in the src/main/resources, but I don't think they'll be loaded automatically. You'll need to make a `Configuration` object, which `Filesystem.get` accepts, or set Spark `hadoopConfiguration` options to do the same

Comment: Also, just pulling it from Maven is generally only done when you have a real Spark cluster running elsewhere (YARN or Kubernetes, for example), then you submit your JAR to that. To get the full experience of running locally, you can't exclusively use the IDE, in my experience