# Spark/Hadoop: Getting "Unsatisfied Link Error: NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0" (with winutils.exe installed correctly)

Tags: java, windows, apache-spark, hadoop

I am using Spark version 3.0.3, and I am having trouble with an "Unsatisfied Link Error" when trying to save Spark Data Frame to my local disk on Windows.  The error originates from "NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0".  I have tried searching for this error on Stack Overflow and other places, but most of the results talk about installing winutils.exe in the correct place, something I have already done.

I have `HADOOP_HOME=C://Tools/winutils`, and inside of `C://Tools/winutils` I have `C://Tools/winutils/bin/winutils.exe`.  I have also tried putting hadoop.dll inside of that directory, but no luck there either.  I've tried 64-bit winutils, and 32-bit winutils with various versions of each but nothing seems to work.  I am using a 64-bit 1.8 Java JDK, but I've tried 32-bit as well, and still the same error.  I have also tried upgrading Spark to 3.2.3, but that doesn't help either.

Here is the exact line of code that crashes my Spark program:

```
df.write()
    .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 10000)
    .option("compression", "gzip")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .format(codec)
    .save(parquetDir);
```

I've tried changing where the save file directory points to, changing the codes from "parquet" to "csv", and I've tried removing each of the `.option()` options as well.

I'm pretty sure it isn't a permissions issue, as I've used the regular Java file API to create files in that location. Adding the line `new File(parquetDir + "/test.txt").createNewFile()` creates a new file in `parquetDir` just fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I can do to fix this issue?  Other people I've spoken with have followed the same directions as me, but it's worked for them, so I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Here is a little more from the stack trace to give more info:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:929)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:910)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:248)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:390)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:466)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022-12-21 15:56:34 WARN  TaskSetManager:69 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, P23566.ieee.org, executor driver): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:929)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:910)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:248)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:390)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:463)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:466)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: HADOOP_HOME needs to be the actual hadoop install directory, not the winutils directory. You should upgrade Spark, though, anyway for other reasons and use Java 11

Comment: Upgrading spark did not help.  If I point HADOOP_HOME to anywhere else than where it is right now, my program crashes much earlier.  As it stands, the crash happens when I try to write the data frame to my local FS, but when HADOOP_HOME points anywhere else, it crashes far before this.

Comment: I have not used Hadoop/Spark on Windows in years. Is there a specific reason you need to do that compared to using WSL2? That way, it doesn't need any DLL files, or winutils, etc.

Comment: You could try the windows `FileSystem` implementation as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74376758/381534