# can't write pyspark dataframe to parquet file on windows

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I can't write pyspark dataframe to parquet file on windows. This code works fine on MacOS pyspark setup. But it doesn't work on Windows. I followed multiple videos and setup everything

Spark

```
C:\Users\aryan>echo %SPARK_HOME%
C:\spark-3.4.2

C:\Users\aryan>spark-shell
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/03/28 05:43:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
24/03/28 05:43:59 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
Spark context Web UI available at http://10.191.10.154:4041
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1711604639907).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.4.2
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.17 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_321)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

and hadoop

```
C:\Users\aryan>hadoop
Usage: hadoop [--config confdir] [--loglevel loglevel] COMMAND
where COMMAND is one of:
  fs                   run a generic filesystem user client
  version              print the version
  jar <jar>            run a jar file
                       note: please use "yarn jar" to launch
                             YARN applications, not this command.
  checknative [-a|-h]  check native hadoop and compression libraries availability
  conftest             validate configuration XML files
  distch path:owner:group:permisson
                       distributed metadata changer
  distcp <srcurl> <desturl> copy file or directories recursively
  archive -archiveName NAME -p <parent path> <src>* <dest> create a hadoop archive
  classpath            prints the class path needed to get the
                       Hadoop jar and the required libraries
  credential           interact with credential providers
  jnipath              prints the java.library.path
  kerbname             show auth_to_local principal conversion
  kdiag                diagnose kerberos problems
  key                  manage keys via the KeyProvider
  trace                view and modify Hadoop tracing settings
  daemonlog            get/set the log level for each daemon
 or
  CLASSNAME            run the class named CLASSNAME

Most commands print help when invoked w/o parameters.

C:\Users\aryan>hadoop -version
java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)

C:\Users\aryan>echo %HADOOP_HOME%
C:\hadoop-3.3.1
```

also copied `winutils.exe` to HADOOP/bin from some github repo

with this code

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pandas as pd
import time
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("My Spark Application") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.7") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "6g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "6g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "1g") \
    .config("spark.memory.fraction", "0.8") \
    .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000) \
    .getOrCreate()



# Start timer for both write operations
start_time = time.time()

# Write the DataFrame to a Parquet file
df_layoff_sk.write.parquet('tech_layoffs_sk.parquet', mode='overwrite')

# Write the DataFrame to a Parquet file
df_housing_sk.write.parquet('housing_market_sk.parquet', mode='overwrite')

# Calculate and print the total time taken for both write operations
total_time_taken = time.time() - start_time
print(f"Total time taken to write both DataFrames to Parquet files: {total_time_taken} seconds")
```

Error

```
{
    "name": "Py4JJavaError",
    "message": "An error occurred while calling o53.parquet.\n: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)\r\n\tat org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$writeAndCommit$3(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)\r\n\tat scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:640)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(FileFormatWriter.scala:304)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:133)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:856)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:387)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:789)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\r\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)\r\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\r\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\r\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\r\n\tat py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)\r\n\tat py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\r\n",
    "stack": "\u001b[1;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;31mPy4JJavaError\u001b[0m                             Traceback (most recent call last)\nCell \u001b[1;32mIn[5], line 5\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m      2\u001b[0m start_time \u001b[38;5;241m=\u001b[39m time\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mtime()\n\u001b[0;32m      4\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;66;03m# Write the DataFrame to a Parquet file\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m----> 5\u001b[0m \u001b[43mdf_layoff_sk\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mwrite\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mparquet\u001b[49m\u001b[43m(\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;124;43m'\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;124;43mtech_layoffs_sk.parquet\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;124;43m'\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43m,\u001b[49m\u001b[43m \u001b[49m\u001b[43mmode\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m=\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;124;43m'\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;124;43moverwrite\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;124;43m'\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43m)\u001b[49m\n\u001b[0;32m      7\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;66;03m# Write the DataFrame to a Parquet file\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[0;32m      8\u001b[0m df_housing_sk\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mwrite\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mparquet(\u001b[38;5;124m'\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124mhousing_market_sk.parquet\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m'\u001b[39m, mode\u001b[38;5;241m=\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m'\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124moverwrite\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m'\u001b[39m)\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mC:\\spark-3.4.2\\python\\pyspark\\sql\\readwriter.py:1656\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mDataFrameWriter.parquet\u001b[1;34m(self, path, mode, partitionBy, compression)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m   1654\u001b[0m     \u001b[38;5;28mself\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mpartitionBy(partitionBy)\n\u001b[0;32m   1655\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28mself\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39m_set_opts(compression\u001b[38;5;241m=\u001b[39mcompression)\n\u001b[1;32m-> 1656\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28;43mself\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43m_jwrite\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mparquet\u001b[49m\u001b[43m(\u001b[49m\u001b[43mpath\u001b[49m\u001b[43m)\u001b[49m\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mC:\\spark-3.4.2\\python\\lib\\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\\py4j\\java_gateway.py:1322\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mJavaMember.__call__\u001b[1;34m(self, *args)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m   1316\u001b[0m command \u001b[38;5;241m=\u001b[39m proto\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mCALL_COMMAND_NAME \u001b[38;5;241m+\u001b[39m\\\n\u001b[0;32m   1317\u001b[0m     \u001b[38;5;28mself\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mcommand_header \u001b[38;5;241m+\u001b[39m\\\n\u001b[0;32m   1318\u001b[0m     args_command \u001b[38;5;241m+\u001b[39m\\\n\u001b[0;32m   1319\u001b[0m     proto\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mEND_COMMAND_PART\n\u001b[0;32m   1321\u001b[0m answer \u001b[38;5;241m=\u001b[39m \u001b[38;5;28mself\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mgateway_client\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39msend_command(command)\n\u001b[1;32m-> 1322\u001b[0m return_value \u001b[38;5;241m=\u001b[39m \u001b[43mget_return_value\u001b[49m\u001b[43m(\u001b[49m\n\u001b[0;32m   1323\u001b[0m \u001b[43m    \u001b[49m\u001b[43manswer\u001b[49m\u001b[43m,\u001b[49m\u001b[43m \u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;28;43mself\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mgateway_client\u001b[49m\u001b[43m,\u001b[49m\u001b[43m \u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;28;43mself\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mtarget_id\u001b[49m\u001b[43m,\u001b[49m\u001b[43m \u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;28;43mself\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mname\u001b[49m\u001b[43m)\u001b[49m\n\u001b[0;32m   1325\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28;01mfor\u001b[39;00m temp_arg \u001b[38;5;129;01min\u001b[39;00m temp_args:\n\u001b[0;32m   1326\u001b[0m     \u001b[38;5;28;01mif\u001b[39;00m \u001b[38;5;28mhasattr\u001b[39m(temp_arg, \u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m_detach\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m):\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mC:\\spark-3.4.2\\python\\pyspark\\errors\\exceptions\\captured.py:169\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mcapture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco\u001b[1;34m(*a, **kw)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    167\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28;01mdef\u001b[39;00m \u001b[38;5;21mdeco\u001b[39m(\u001b[38;5;241m*\u001b[39ma: Any, \u001b[38;5;241m*\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;241m*\u001b[39mkw: Any) \u001b[38;5;241m-\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;241m>\u001b[39m Any:\n\u001b[0;32m    168\u001b[0m     \u001b[38;5;28;01mtry\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[1;32m--> 169\u001b[0m         \u001b[38;5;28;01mreturn\u001b[39;00m \u001b[43mf\u001b[49m\u001b[43m(\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m*\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43ma\u001b[49m\u001b[43m,\u001b[49m\u001b[43m \u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m*\u001b[39;49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m*\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mkw\u001b[49m\u001b[43m)\u001b[49m\n\u001b[0;32m    170\u001b[0m     \u001b[38;5;28;01mexcept\u001b[39;00m Py4JJavaError \u001b[38;5;28;01mas\u001b[39;00m e:\n\u001b[0;32m    171\u001b[0m         converted \u001b[38;5;241m=\u001b[39m convert_exception(e\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mjava_exception)\n\nFile \u001b[1;32mC:\\spark-3.4.2\\python\\lib\\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\\py4j\\protocol.py:326\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mget_return_value\u001b[1;34m(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m    324\u001b[0m value \u001b[38;5;241m=\u001b[39m OUTPUT_CONVERTER[\u001b[38;5;28mtype\u001b[39m](answer[\u001b[38;5;241m2\u001b[39m:], gateway_client)\n\u001b[0;32m    325\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28;01mif\u001b[39;00m answer[\u001b[38;5;241m1\u001b[39m] \u001b[38;5;241m==\u001b[39m REFERENCE_TYPE:\n\u001b[1;32m--> 326\u001b[0m     \u001b[38;5;28;01mraise\u001b[39;00m Py4JJavaError(\n\u001b[0;32m    327\u001b[0m         \u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124mAn error occurred while calling \u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;132;01m{0}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;132;01m{1}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;132;01m{2}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;124m.\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;130;01m\\n\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39m\n\u001b[0;32m    328\u001b[0m         \u001b[38;5;28mformat\u001b[39m(target_id, \u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m.\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m, name), value)\n\u001b[0;32m    329\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28;01melse\u001b[39;00m:\n\u001b[0;32m    330\u001b[0m     \u001b[38;5;28;01mraise\u001b[39;00m Py4JError(\n\u001b[0;32m    331\u001b[0m         \u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124mAn error occurred while calling \u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;132;01m{0}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;132;01m{1}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;132;01m{2}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;124m. Trace:\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;130;01m\\n\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;132;01m{3}\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;130;01m\\n\u001b[39;00m\u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39m\n\u001b[0;32m    332\u001b[0m         \u001b[38;5;28mformat\u001b[39m(target_id, \u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m.\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m, name, value))\n\n\u001b[1;31mPy4JJavaError\u001b[0m: An error occurred while calling o53.parquet.\n: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)\r\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)\r\n\tat org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$writeAndCommit$3(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)\r\n\tat scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:640)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(FileFormatWriter.scala:304)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:133)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:856)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:387)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:789)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\r\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)\r\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\r\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\r\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\r\n\tat py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)\r\n\tat py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\r\n"
}
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [Why all these \`HADOOP\_HOME\` and Winutils errors with Spark on Windows if Hadoop not used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73503205/why-all-these-hadoop-home-and-winutils-errors-with-spark-on-windows-if-hadoop).  Use bare naked fs to work on windows